# How could I set the length of a line to stretch in a MAUI application?

Tags: maui

I would like to use a line in a MAUI project, and this is the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/shapes/line?view=net-maui-7.0

But i would like, in an horizontal line, to set that automatically the line use all the space from left to right. I don't see stretch options like another controls.

I could set a very long length, for example 10000, but I would like to know if there is a better way.

Thanks.

Comment: Line should support HorizontalOptions, but I have no idea if it actually behaves as expected.

Comment: What do you need this for? If you could provide some context, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Just I want to create a header for a list view, to know what data has the columns that I am showing in the list view. So I want to show a line as separator between the header and the list view that fill the full width of the screen.

Answer (score 6):

To answer directly your question: since `X2` is bindable, you can bind it to the width of itself:

```xml
<Line Stroke="Red" X2="{Binding Width, Source={RelativeSource Self}}" HorizontalOptions="Fill" StrokeThickness="3" />
```

[image]

My advice: MS has been using `BoxView` or `BorderView` for lines since forever, I guess it's better performance-wise as well. You should use the other solution instead unless you absolutely have to use Line.

Comment: A line is a shape and hence is drawn whereas Boxview is not drawn, drawing controls is usually more expensive, so I agree you should not use line for such scenarios

Answer (score 0):

try the below code for horizontal line

```
<Style x:Key="HorizontalBoarder" TargetType="BoxView">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
</Style>
 <BoxView
         Margin="0,5"
            Style="{StaticResource HorizontalBoarder}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A [`Line`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/shapes/line?view=net-maui-7.0) is a [`Shape`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/shapes/?view=net-maui-7.0) with the [`Aspect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.shapes.shape.aspect?view=net-maui-7.0#microsoft-maui-controls-shapes-shape-aspect) property of type [`Stretch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.stretch?view=net-maui-7.0).

To stretch a `Line` to fill the space of its layout, below a `Grid` row with default horizontal layout `Fill`, use the `Aspect` value `Uniform`:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Line Grid.Row="0" Stroke="Red" X1="0" X2="100" Aspect="Uniform" />

  <Line Grid.Row="1" Stroke="Green" X1="0" X2="100" Aspect="None" />

</Grid>
```